# How to print the page numbers which has changes after comparing the word documents

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

How to print the page numbers  which has changes after comparing the word documents. 
I have written the following code to find the differences using vb script. Kindly help in identify and print the page numbers.

```
    > Declaring FSO
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        objFSO.DeleteFile("C:\Users\amunaga\Desktop\POC doc comparision\POC\DocumentsWithChanges\*.docx")

    'Getting absolute path
        Dim objFSO
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim CurrentDirectory
        CurrentDirectory = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

        Set objExcel = createobject("Excel.Application") 
        Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.open("C:\Users\amunaga\Desktop\POC doc comparision\POC\Report.xlsx")    
        Set objSheet=  objWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")   
        Set objRange = objSheet.UsedRange
            RowsCount = objRange.Rows.Count      

    For Iterator = 2 To RowsCount

        BaseDocName= objSheet.Cells(Iterator,2).Value  
        NewDocName = objSheet.Cells(Iterator,3).Value    

        strBaseDoc = "C:\Users\amunaga\Desktop\POC doc comparision\POC\BaseDocuments\"&BaseDocName&".docx"
        strNewDoc  = "C:\Users\amunaga\Desktop\POC doc comparision\POC\NewDocuments\"&NewDocName&".docx"    

        fContinue = True

        fContinue = objFSO.FileExists(strBaseDoc)
        fContinue = objFSO.FileExists(strNewDoc)


        If fContinue = False Then
                MsgBox "Invalid File Paths" ,vbExclamation ,"Error"
        Else

                Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
                Set opnstrBaseDoc=objWord.Documents.Open(strBaseDoc)
                Set opnstrNewDoc=objWord.Documents.Open(strNewDoc)

             > Comparing 2 documents
                Set Dcomp=objWord.Comparedocuments(opnstrBaseDoc,opnstrNewDoc)
                RevCount=Dcomp.Revisions.count


                If RevCount<>0 Then
                    'msgbox RevCount
                    objSheet.Cells(Iterator,4).Value ="There are changes.Please check " &BaseDocName&"_CHANGE.docx file in  'DocumentsWithChanges' folder"
                    objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
                    objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 ("C:\Users\amunaga\Desktop\POC doc comparision\POC\DocumentsWithChanges\"&BaseDocName&"_CHANGE.docx")                    

                    objWord.Quit SaveChanges
                    Set objWord=Nothing 

                Else
                    objSheet.Cells(Iterator,4).Value ="No changes in the content"   

                    objWord.Quit SaveChanges
                    Set objWord=Nothing

                End If      
        End If
    Next   

    objWorkBook.Close
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objSheet=Nothing                                
    Set objWorkBook=Nothing                               
    Set objExcel=Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
```

How to print the page numbers which has changes after comparing the word documents. I have written the following code to find the differences using vb script. Kindly help in identify and print the page numbers.

Comment: According to the [Word Object Model documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.comparedocuments), `Comparedocuments` returns a `Document`. The *Word Object Model* documentation shows you what information is available in `Document`. I don't see anything in there for *pages different during comparision*. It's not contained in the [Revision object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.revision), either.

Comment: Yes i am taking revision count. Kindly check my code again

Comment: I know you're taking revision count. But **Revision** does not include page numbers, as you can see by following the link to the documentation for the **Revision** object I provided. Kindly read my comment again.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. kindly suggest me any solution to solve this.

Comment: I've explained already that the information isn't available AFAICT. Did you *read* the links I provided above?

Comment: Sir, I understood your comments, thank you. But i am asking for any other solutions which can solve my problem ( for example: page number object etc...). Kindly give me some solution to resolve this as its very urgent to me

Comment: @AdithyAKumar There doesn't look to be any conventional way to accomplish this - you would need some lengthy workaround written which would undoubtedly be a pain to write.